# Android - TextInputLayout doesn't wrap hint of TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have a simple `TextInputEditText` nested in `TextTnputLayout`.

I am trying to make the of `TIL` to be as long as the hint given in `TIET`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="This is a hint"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

But the problem is, it doesn't show anything
[image: Nothing]

I have to set `TIL`'s width to `match_parent` or just any other width other than `wrap_content`. But I want to the width to be dynamic as in, the width of `TIL` follows the length of the hint provided. Is it possible? If yes, how to do that?

I am using support library version `26.0.2` btw.

Yvette Colomb's answer is close, the `TIL` wraps the `TIET` but the fancy animation doesn't work there. It might be because the animation won't start if hints are set in execution?

Comment: I don't write anything in Java, it's a test layout

Comment: Try simple EditText insted of TextInputEditText and set EditTextHeight matchparent

Comment: At first I was using `EditText`, and tried all possible match_parent

Comment: What ypu want exactly?

Comment: Have you given layout_weight to its parent layout in height attribute ??

Comment: @Ankita I want a textinputlayout which will follow the hint in the edittext for its width. I still want to keep the animation of hint moving above the edittext.

Answer (score 6):

You can do so, by setting the hint in the java code.

Remove the hint from the xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/inputTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Declare and initialise the TextInputEditText in the activity and set the hint.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextInputEditText inputTxt = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.inputTxt);
    inputTxt.setHint("This is a hint");
}
```

[image]

This will wrap the text to the width of the hint as you type (not saying this is how it goes for all devices)

[image]

Then expand the width when you've entered the text.

[image]

To answer your updated question.

How to make the input layout grow as we enter input.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/txtInputL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/inputTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
```

The Java.

```
final TextInputEditText inputTxt = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.inputTxt);
inputTxt.setHint("This is a hint");
final TextInputLayout txtInputL = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.txtInputL);
txtInputL.setMinimumWidth(300);
txtInputL.setHint("This is a hint");
```

I've added a floating hint:

[image]

As we're typing:

[image]

If you have any other questions about this, please ask a new question.

Comment: Ohh that's almost right to my need actually! I also need the text hint to be animated though, as this defeats the purpose of `TIL` :(.. I should add more info to the question

Comment: No, that cute animation when user enters a letter and the hint moves up so that I don't need to use `TV` above `ET` to show user which field they are inputting like normal form..

Comment: Oh! So it's different?? I thought it's the same, because that's basically what `TIL` does lol, okay I've now adjusted the length on the `ET`s depending on screen size though, so no need for another question just yet, thanks!

Comment: This didn't answer my question, but it was close though, I thought that upvote was from me so I didn't upvote lol, here, take another upvote!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this from xml instead, just set the hint for both TextInputLayout and TextInputEdittext and it will work then to make the TextInputEdittext grow as you are typing you have to set the it maxlines="1" and the layout_height to wrap_content as below

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="This is edittext">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:hint="This is edittext
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

I hope this help someone
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/txt_inputLayout_gify"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_gift_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="This is hint." />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I have to make `TIL` to `match_parent`?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan It will work, yes.. I know, but.. I asked about dynamic width `TIL` following its hint length, so by making it `match_parent` doesn't help.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a type of workaround, for me I wanted to show Country Code in a disabled Material Design styled EditText, but same as you I was unable to use the wrap_context inside TextInputLayout.

So as a workaround I added the hint text in both TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText, and since I had a predefined text inside the TextInputEditText, the hint of TextInputEditText never appeared on screen, but made space for the hint of TextInputLayout to be visible.

Here is what I did...

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="16dp">
    ...
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/country_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Country code"
        app:hintTextColor="#737373"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+91"
            android:hint="Country Code"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textColor="#737373"
            .../>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

P.S. You might want to add a few more characters in the TextInputEditText hint, as that is what is controlling the spacing. Also the constraint layout is there just because I had other elements in the activity, you can avoid it and use any of your root view.

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set your xml like so:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     android:id="@+id/text_field_layout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="15sp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_text_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Now, adjust the size of the input_text_field to be **BY THE SIZE OF THE HINT**, depending on the hint size, like so:

```
val tf = input_text_field
val layout = text_field_layout
val hint = "Hint"

val measureText = tf.paint.measureText(hint).toInt()
tf.width = tf.paddingLeft + tf.paddingRight + measureText.toInt()
layout.hint = hint
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="This is a hint"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work.. I tried it, and I just tried it again lol, and it still doesn't work :(